# subset data into dataframe iteratively - R

Tags: r, dataframe

For this dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(
  col = c("a","f","g","a")
)
```

How do I subset it for each unique letter and input it into a new dataframe like so?:

```
sheet_a <- subset(df, col == "a")
sheet_f <- subset(df, col == "f")
sheet_g <- subset(df, col == "g")
```

I think I need to use a column of unique characters using the below code in a for loop but I'm not sure how

```
uniq.name_col <- unique(as.vector(df$col))
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: A better plan might be to store the result in a list, which is easy to do with `split(df,df$col)`. If you're dead set on having them saved as objects, you could use `list2env(split(df,df$col),envir = globalenv())`. You would then have data.frames named `a`, `f`, and `g` in the global environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, that includes code for exporting dataframes to environment:

```
#Create list
List <- split(df,df$col)
#Set to envir al dataframes
list2env(List,.GlobalEnv)
```